# Permissions for Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am fairly new to Amazon S3.

I am trying to give permission to the files in a folder and subfolder that I have uploaded to S3 from my local system.

Here is the code:

```
static string sourcepath = @"D:\SVN\Tis_REL_4_4_1003_2\Media\Includes";
        static string destinationpath = @"Media\Includes".ToLower();
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (client = GetS3Client())
            {
                //var sInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourcepath);
                //var filenew = Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath);
                foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(sourcepath))
                {
                    File.Move(file, file.ToLowerInvariant());
                }
                var fInfo = new S3DirectoryInfo(client, awsBucketName, destinationpath);
                fInfo.CopyFromLocal(sourcepath);
            }
        }
```

Now when I call any of the files inside these folder I get access denied.

Is there a way to give permissions without using S3 browser since I am getting an error when I try to change the permissions.

Also I am not using `putobjectrequest` to put the objects in the bucket so `CannedACL` may also not be an answer.

Comment: Yes, you can certainly add permissions via the API, but it's first worth understanding the current situation. Can you explain more about what you are doing? What do you mean by "when I call any of the files"? If you look at the object in the S3 management console, what permissions are displayed in the object's "permissions" tab?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein What i mean by any of the files is that i am calling the file via Combress where you specify the link for the file to be rendered there when i copy the link to the browser to check permission i see Access Denied. and since i didnot create the bucket i dont even have the rights to see the permissions in the permission tab of the S3 browser.